# iptables. Bastion network with acces to Internet. How to set up rules?

Tags: linux-networking

I'm trying to set up a bastion network with lan access to internet. This is my diagram.

[image]

I have internet acces in the linux firewall (I'm using a lubuntu 16.04). And I can ping from lubuntuclon (192.168.10.2)  to the firewall (192.168.10.1) perfectly. So I think is working. The problem is that I cannot acces internet from the LAN. I think it's a matter of iptables but It's not working as expected.  This are the iptables rules I'm using:

Flush the rules:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -Z
iptables -t nat -F
```

Politics:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
```

Rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.10.0/24 -i enp0s8 -j ACCEPT -->so the LAN has access to the firewall
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.0/24 -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE  --> so the lan has internet access
```

but when I ping 8.8.8.8 from lubunutuclon or winxpclon I got no response. I cannot acces internet from browser neither, of course.

I think my rules are wrong. But I cannot figure why. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to enable ip forwarding on the Linux firewall:

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Comment: I try it, but it didn't work. Still can't ping the linuxfirewall or the lubuntuclon. However, if I run tcpdump -i enp0s3 I can see the response packets but they go trough enps03 instead of enp0s8, any idea? and thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you see Something with tcpdump on enp0s8 (while testing ping) : ARP frames, ICMP packets ?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I can ping ok now. (I think the ip forwarding do works after all). The firewall see and respond to the pings of lubuntuclon.  Now I need to access internet from lubuntuclon.  What iptables rules do I need to set? thank you for yor help.

Comment: You do not need any other rule, since the default policy is ACCEPT. It should already work correctly.

Comment: mmm... are you sure I'm not missing some Nat rule? Beacause I cannot acces internet from lubuntuclon. I think the linux firewall needs to translate the 192.168.10.5 (lubuntu address) to 192.168.1.2.  I'm trying that, but still no success...

Comment: ok. I was missing a rule with iptables.  iptables -t nat POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE  solve the problem.  I'm marking this answer as solved, beause the ip fowarding was the solution for what i was asking. Thank you very much.